# Update one deeply structured javascript object from another in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a javascript object (viewModel) that is binded to view . I'm getting new version of it (newViewModel) from server . (You can imagine stock market price application at this point)

I don't want to bind newViewModel because I dont want to loose old viewModel's reference.

So I need update all properties of my existing javascript object from server response !

This is maybe javascript question but my viewModel have so many observable properties and sub-properties. (knockout's observable)

Ps: jQuery's $.extend does not work.

UPDATED (It seems ok):

ko.mapping.fromJS(newViewModel,viewModel); seems working .. I could not recognize it, because "Vs.Net Intellisense" did not show overloads of it.

My object is very deeply structured. if I see any problems I will inform you.

UPDATED (Does not work):

viewModel.x[] length=2

newViewModel.x[] length=12

The code above replaces all x with new ones. (I lost viewModel.x[0],viewModel.x[1] references) !!

So my html is not synchronized with my objects. viewModel.x[0] in the basket on the right side but it
is not in the basket on the left side (screen)

Comment: I think the "Mapping" plugin is what you're looking for: knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic way for it.. Because I need to match old array elements with news.  "Code"  needs to know "keys" of array elements..

I visit all array elements if I could find newElement in my old array I update oldElement's properties if I could not find I add newElement to oldArray.

Painful but I had to do.